# Visible raw file in github private repositories using git large files

Tags: git, github

I’m using git large files in one of my github private repositories and all was just good, but when I copy and paste the link for the [raw data](https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/gabrielbdornas/glf-teste-object-arquive/main/teste.csv?token=AL3FTWVFMX7YXDEFQYL2I3LAVWWIG) in an unlogged browser it was possible to see it. Is there a way to solve this problem?

In git large files page there is a topic saying “Keep the same access controls and permissions for large files as the rest of your Git repository when working with a remote host like GitHub.”

Is that true? Is there a way to configure the repo to hidden my information? I’ve tried to understand one of [glfs tutorials](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-config.5.ronn) but couldn’t find the ansewr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you've posted contains a token in the URL.  That token exists to make it possible to view the raw URL even though the URL is on a different domain, and it contains credentials to permit someone to view that file.

Normally, the access to Git LFS files is restricted to the same access as the rest of your repository.  Only parties who can read the files in your repository can get a valid raw data link like you've gotten, so as long as you don't distribute links to files in your private repository, you should be fine.

The token in the URL is specific to a file and a user, and usually it is sufficient to change your password to expire all the links.